# how to create a loop at the bottom of sphere?

Tags: rendering

I am trying to add a loop here at the bottom of this sphere to create legs for the my character. But due to some it is nor working , Can anyone help please? I have tried subdivide too but because of some reason it is not showing the grid though it is applying. I am adding a image for your reference. Please help I have no idea what to do now [image]

Comment: What is it that you want? A loop or a grid?

Comment: Loopcut can be added only i between two other loops (Ctrl+R). The way to add a loop for this n-gon you should use an **Inset** operator ... but since you need to split area into a two "legs" loops @moonboots answer is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should begin with less vertices in my opinion, but from what you have you could first fill and subdivide between the 2 opposite vertices:

[image]

Then select all the vertices around, extrude inwards:

[image]

Activate the *LoopTools* addon, right click > *LoopTools > Circle*:

[image]

Extrude down:

[image]

Symmetrize, either with a *Mirror* modifier or with *Mesh > Symmetrize* (choose the axis in the *Operator* box):

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you so much @moonboots